# Omit the Front Page when Using Contextual Filters?

Tags: blocks, views

Content on my site is set up via taxonomy term, and I've created a view using contextual filters which does a fabulous job of sorting all the content to the appropriate page.

However, on the front page we want to present that content differently, so I have created a block which presents anything marked "front" to appear inside it.

The two are mutually exclusive, as I have filtered the data so that ONLY front page stuff appears in the block, and NO front page items appear in the page view.

This is problematic, however, as some of these highlighted items should appear on other pages in the Web site.  Removing the 'exclude home' filter from the page view, however, makes the page view of items marked "front" appear beneath the block, which we don't want.

In order to get the content on the home page AND elsewhere content owners are required to enter the data twice -- unless I can get this fixed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First : NEVER enter data twice. You're sure you'll regret it sooner or later, and it's always the sign something's wrong with the design.

As for your problem, you could probably set up a Views Attachment or a plain other view to add nodes with different criteria.

Or perhaps you could use [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) or another module of that kind to differenciate your nodes more precisely ?

Comment: Thank you - we know twice entering data is wrong, which is why we want to get away from this.  :)                                                                                                                         Adding an additional view doesn't work because the "default" view appears beneath the block view or attachment, so I'm getting duplicate data.  I'm now toying with telling drupal just not to print nodes on the home page using hide(content[node]) (with proper coding) - however, this prohibits the nodes in the block view from showing, too.  Any other ideas?  Many thanks...

Comment: The solution should be data based, not display based. I still don't understand why you can't code different views or displays (views' terminology) for the non-front pages.